# Can I use Liferay 6.1.1 with primefaces 6.2, extensions 6.2.8, mojarra 2.3.2 and java JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, liferay, java-6

Can I use this together? Liferay 6.1.1 with new Primefaces 6.2? JDK 1.6 or up?

I have problems with deployment...

> at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_20] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_20]
>
> org/primefaces/extensions/component/documentviewer/DocumentViewer :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: Post 'Unsupported major.minor version 51.0' in google and you have an answer to this error

Comment: PrimeFaces Extensions I believe requires JDK7 or higher.

Comment: What is the latest version of primefaces and primefaces extensions for java jdk 1.6? I have solution for my problem here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/fluidgrid/dynaform.jsf , but at the bottom are versions...

Comment: According to the [Liferay Portal 6.1 Compatibility Matrix](https://web.liferay.com/documents/14/21598941/Liferay+Portal+6.1+EE+Compatibility+Matrix.pdf), the latest version of Liferay 6.1 EE supports Oracle JDK 6 and JDK 7. Supposedly PrimeFaces 6.2 supports [Java 1.6+](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) so you should be able to use JDK 7 to run this configuration. Note that PrimeFaces 6.2 has only been tested for compatibility for Liferay 7.0+ by the Liferay Faces team.